# How to call a function in Javascript when a input changes value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to call function `xxx` when input type text `id="username"` change value ?

first, when you fill data into

```
<input type="text" name="thingy" onkeypress="updateInput(this.value)" onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" />
```

Then data in

```
<input type="text" name="thingy" onkeypress="updateInput(this.value)" onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" />
```

will change value.

OK, when input `name="thingy"` change i want to call function `xxx` , i try this code but not work.

How can i do that ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInput(ish){
    document.getElementById("username").value = ish;
}
</script>
<form id="main_fid">
    input1 : <input type="text" name="thingy" onkeypress="updateInput(this.value)" onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" /> 
    <span id="mySpan"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>


<script>
function xxx() {
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'other.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#username_send_value_fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySpan').show();
                    $('#mySpan').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
}
</script>
<br>
<form id="username_send_value_fid">
    input2 : <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onchange="xxx()" readonly/>  
</form>
```

Comment: So use an `onchange` handler there.

Comment: Why call a seperate function?  You are setting the value of `username` to `ish` so why not just call the ajax after you set the value in the first function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think calling xxx() on "onchange" event or inside updateInput(ish) will give the same effect.

Try

```
function updateInput(ish){
  document.getElementById("username").value = ish;
  xxx();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#username").on( "change", handler )
```

or in short form

```
$("#username").change( handler )
```

And get rid of the inline `onchange` attribute. You will also need to wrap the code in a [ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#username").change( handler )
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

**Added after reading the question a bit more carefully:**

If you want to link your `input name="thingy"` to `username` you can do something like this:

```
$('input[name="thingy"]').change(function(){
    $("#username").val( $(this).val() ).trigger('change');
});
```

This will update the value of `username` and then trigger a change event as if the user had typed in the input.

However if what you are trying to accomplish is something like validating the uniqueness of an input the is no reason to jump though so many hoops - just call your ajax handler straight from the `username` change event.

Comment: and how to call function xxx ?

Comment: $("#username").on( "change", xxx )

Comment: please stop calling porn... :3